# Allow returnline in textarea with regular expression

Tags: php, html, regex

I would like to allow **returnlines** in a Form **textarea**. I haven't found the way to add this possibility
to my *regular expression*. Will the **return line** be stored in the database?

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <textarea name="description" spellcheck="true" maxlength="500"></textarea> 
</form>
```

And the PHP code with the regular expression to regulate the `textarea` input (**true** = match the regex = store to database):

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿç0-9 !?’',.-]+$/i", $POST['description'] )) {
    return false;
}
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked in the database how the submitted texts are stored? Is there any problem?. I don't see what the purpose is of the regular expression. I just see return true/false, but you give no info as to what that means, or what is done with that result.

Comment: I can not check in the database because the text is not stored in the database as long as my regex expression doesent allow the returnlines. I dident put all the code but the regular expression is just the way I want the textarea to be formated to be accepted in the database.

Comment: So `return false` in your code means you will not store it in the database? Is that it? You should add that in your question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match new lines (and carriage returns) by adding `\n` and `\r`:

```
/^[a-zàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿç0-9 \n\r!?’',.-]+$/i
```

But maybe you want to allow all types of white space (like tabs, non-breaking space, ...). Then you can better use `\s`:

```
/^[a-zàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿç0-9\s!?’',.-]+$/i
```

Listing all allowable letters might be difficult. There will always be that one other character... like `ò`. If you are willing to allow anything that could be called a letter in some language or alphabet (even Greek, Cyrillic), then use the [`\pL` escape](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) in combination with the [unicode modifier `u`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) at the end.

Note you can also use `\d` for matching digits:

```
/^[\pL\d\s!?’',.-]+$/iu
```